# WAS6.1 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun/instrument/InstrumentationImpl.getObjectSize0

Tags: instrumentation, websphere-6.1

I am trying to use the classmexer to profile some instance memory runtime.I have set the following as Generic JVM arguments in Webshpere 6.1:

-javaagent:c:/Downloads/classmexer.jar

Following exception is thrown:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun/instrument/InstrumentationImpl.getObjectSize0(Ljava/lang/Object;)J
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.getObjectSize(InstrumentationImpl.java:116)
    at com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf0(MemoryUtil.java:178)

It works fine standalone though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the dependencies and classmexer to shared library directory, probably AppServer/lib/ext. The Exception is thrown because WAS doesn't search for everything required from the PATH set in your shell. That is why it still works as standalone.